# 2D CAD Image Overlay, Alignment, Lite Markup Software

Tags: image, svg, image-processing, 2d, cad

We interested in developing a lite weight 2D Image Software. Our available formats are; CGM, PDF, STL, 3MF, OBJ, IFC, PLY, HTML, JT, VRML, IGES, PNG, JPG, GIF, TIF, BMP, STEP, DXF/DWG.  These are the available output file types from the high-end 3D CAD software.  Basic requirements; view images overlay one another with tranparent backgrounds. Alignment based on critical points [can be defined within XML format].  Some basic markup such as horizontal and vertical dimensions. The images are simple profiles does not include any shaded images. Believe it should be scalar vector image and NOT raster. We have found information on SVG with HTML5, WPF, etc. So, question; any advice on where to start? Our knowledge base is C++/VB.Net/C#/HTML/CSS/XML/JScript/VBScript/PYTHON. We also have access to SharePoint/Power BI/Teams/Power Apps Canvas. SVG is not an available format exported from the 3D CAD software.  This is a very basic set of requirements of just image overlays. But we want to go with the most current and logical path.  Any suggestions and/or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like a job description. if you want to hire someone, there are sites for that. please take the [tour], review [ask], and check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Chris, no not a job description, asking for suggestions of possible avenues. We want to take advantage of the latest technologies and google does not always produce the best and LATEST solutions.  Nobody knows all the best solutions.  As an example, we are considering HTML5 with SVG format for the viewer and develop an additional application that would generate the SVG file format exported from the 3D CAD software since currently SVG is not available as a core format.

Comment: ... Just not sure if that would be the BEST road to take.  Maybe there are other ideas.  Maybe a C# application for the viewer using one of the current 3d CAD’s core vector image formats.  Then it’s not required to create the additional application to export the SVG format.  It’s not that general.  Listed the current core image formats available and the viewer would be a lite weight 2D viewer with limited markup ability. This question falls under the following categories: software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: Thank you, K J. We also looked into PDF as a solution. Some of the ability is available with PDF but not all.  The current/potential users’ requirements are not currently available with RasterEx and we already have Oracle’s AutoVue.  Doesn’t accommodate user requirements and the enhancements estimates were very expensive. So, the decision to develop internal software.  Our IT and Innovation group have researched several outside software packages, and none give exactly what the users require. Another major automaker also developed their own internal software for the exact some functionality.